# Using sed with regex to remove text from a file

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to use sed with regex to remove specific patterns from a file.
Here is the command I'm using:

```
sed '/location .*?\/\s+{(?:[\w\W]+?)}\s*(?=(?:location|$))/d'
```

Here is a sample text I'm testing with:

```
location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location ~*  .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
            expires 365d;
        }

        location ~*  .(pdf)$ {
            expires 30d;
        }

        location ~ \.php$
                {
                        try_files $uri =404;
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        include /etc/nginx/nginx_limits.conf;
                        if (-f $request_filename)
                        {
                                fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/php73/sockets/rgeoipdsm1.sock;
                        }
                }
        location ~ / {
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ^ / {
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ / {
                        if (-f $request_filename)
                        {
                                fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/php73/sockets/rgeoipdsm1.sock;
                        }
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

location ~ \.png {

}

location ~ / {
}
```

What I'm expecting to see after running sed:

```
location ~*  .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }
    
    location ~*  .(pdf)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }

        location ~ \.php$
                {
                        try_files $uri =404;
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        include /etc/nginx/nginx_limits.conf;
                        if (-f $request_filename)
                        {
                                fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/php73/sockets/rgeoipdsm1.sock;
                        }
                }
    location ~ \.png {

}
```

But after running sed I get no changes at all, it seems to match nothing.
Is it possible to fine-tune this command (perhaps with escape characters?) so it'll remove the required patterns?

Comment: Try `sed '/^[[:blank:]]*location .*\/[[:blank:]]*{[[:blank:]]*$/,/^[[:blank:]]*}[[:blank:]]*$/d' yourfile > newfile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*location .*\/[[:blank:]]*{[[:blank:]]*$/,/^[[:blank:]]*}[[:blank:]]*$/d' yourfile > newfile
```

This sed command finds blocks of lines between line matching `^[[:blank:]]*location .*\/[[:blank:]]*{[[:blank:]]*$` and a line matching `^[[:blank:]]*}[[:blank:]]*$`, and removes them (with `d`).

The `^[[:blank:]]*location .*\/[[:blank:]]*{[[:blank:]]*$` regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[[:blank:]]*` - zero or more spaces/tabs
- `location`  - a `location`  string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `[[:blank:]]*{[[:blank:]]*` - a `{~ enclosed with zero or more spaces/tabs
- `$` - end of string.

The `^[[:blank:]]*}[[:blank:]]*$` regex matches a string that only contains a single `}` char eclosed with optional spaces/tabs.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/location ([~^] )?\/ \{/{:a;N;/^(\s*)location.*\n\1\}\s*$/d;ba}' file
```

Match the `location` required, then append lines until the white space before the closing `}` matches the opening lines initial white space and delete those line.